# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

```
 var newWindow=window.open('','export');

                // Puts focus on the newWindow
                if (window.focus) {
                    newWindow.focus();
                }
```

I want to print my webpage then it works fine in Mozilla but not in google chrome

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for `window.focus`, but then trying to *use* `newWindow.focus`. Be consistent about what you check for and then use.

Comment: var newWindow=window.open('','export');

            if (newWindow.focus) {
                newWindow.focus();
            } it's give same error on this line if (newWindow.focus) {